# Delete parent node if two child nodes are empty

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML-File. `

```
    <objects>
       <infos>
          <rep-id-name id="12345"/>
          <rep-name>IT</rep-name>
          <create-user>354832</create-user>
          <update-user>354832</update-user>
          <create-date>2013-04-22T12:37:56.798Z</create-date>
          <update-date>2013-04-22T14:41:16.299Z</update-date>
          <parameter-definition/>
          <column-definition/>
       </infos>
       <infos>
          <rep-id-name id="255962905"/>
          <rep-name>IT</rep-name>
          <create-user>35483</create-user>
          <update-user>35483</update-user>
          <create-date>2013-04-22T12:37:56.798Z</create-date>
          <update-date>2013-04-22T12:43:44.238Z</update-date>
          <parameter-definition>
             <contains-loc-string>True</contains-loc-string>
          </parameter-definition>
          <column-definition/>
       </infos>
</objects>
```

How can i check if the two child nodes (**parameter-definition** and **column-definition**) are empty and delete the full parent node. So the expected result is:

```
<objects>
    <infos>
          <rep-id-name id="255962905"/>
          <rep-name>IT</rep-name>
          <create-user>35483</create-user>
          <update-user>35483</update-user>
          <create-date>2013-04-22T12:37:56.798Z</create-date>
          <update-date>2013-04-22T12:43:44.238Z</update-date>
          <parameter-definition>
             <contains-loc-string>True</contains-loc-string>
          </parameter-definition>
          <column-definition/>
       </infos>
</objects>
```

Comment: Show what you've already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the following template rule in your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="infos[not(parameter-definition/node() 
                           or column-definition/node())]"/>
```

I've interpreted "empty" here as meaning "has no child nodes" - other definitions are possible, for example you might want to allow comments or whitespace text. This will also treat the elements as empty if they are absent.

Comment: Awesome. I had the problem with the "or"-operator. Thank you!